# turning SPARQL queries into visualizations

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, rdf, sparql

I'm currently working on a site which will primarily feature charts and visualizations in general.  The data for these visualizations will be taken from a SPARQL endpoint.  For example, one bar chart would show total papers published, categorized by year.  Right now, the URI's for these papers are imported as nodes using Miles Worthington's Linked Data Import (formerly RDFimporter).  Using mappings, I'm able to store values for these papers (year, author, etc.) in custom fields (or fields of nodes of custom content type).  Then, I'm selecting the papers (nodes) from Drupal's database (MySQL?) and processing the values I'm interested in.

```
        // load the node
        $node = node_load($array['nid']);

        // store year in $output
        $fgi_year = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_year');
        $output = field_view_value('node', $node, 'field_year', $fgi_year[0]);
```

With some iteration, the above gives me the information I need about years in which papers were published.  The values are then passed to an instance of gRaphael, which renders a bar chart with no problem.

This is one way to visualize data returned from SPARQL queries, but I'm interested in possibly more efficient ways of doing this.  The final site will probably have thousands of nodes in the end, and I'm not sure if this will decrease performance substantially.  Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you heard or [Spark](http://km.aifb.kit.edu/sites/spark/) at all?

It's a client side JS library for making SPARQL queries and visualizing the results.  If the results require minimal/no processing it may be better to use something like this and put most of the work on the client rather than doing everything server side.  This way all you have to do is generate the relevant SPARQL queries server side.

Comment: Thanks, RobV! I had never heard of Spark before you mentioned it.  Spark seems to be a great way to return SPARQL query results, but I haven't found anything substantial as far as actual visualizations go (just a simple pie chart and table, really).  Do you have any experience with SPARK visualizations?

Comment: No sorry, just something I'd come across in the past and thought it looked interesting

Comment: just a quick note for the future: if your SPARQL queries will be returning many rows (for me, e.g. 42,000 rows), Spark is not a good option because it queries the SPARQL endpoint each time it's invoked, causing a severe lag time.  Consider a database and/or caching system instead for your data to be visualized.